How to remove iterm2 line focus on click?
I'm currently running into an issue with iterm2 on my new macbook that I didn't had on my previous macbook, I imported my old config but it appears a new thing happens when I click on a line, it focuses the lines of its response, for exemple, when I enter echo test lines in terminal, then I click on the "block" of command, it focus the block in a lighter background color (see image1).
Has anyone know how to solve this issue ?
image1
I looked up in the settings but didn't found the one that causes this.
Thanks for the help

uncheck this:
iterm - settings - selection - clicking on a command selects it to restrict find and filter

